# utility to make uboot customization/building easy?

Tags: makefile, linux-kernel, u-boot

Is there a quick and dirty application or script somewhere that allows me to customize uboot relatively painless and fast?

At current state, to my limited understanding, this is what I need to do if I wanted to build my own bootloder using uboot: I have to first be an intermediate level expert on GNU make as well as makefile scripting, then I have to study extensively the makefiles of uboot in order to decide what "child" makefiles I must include and what are the lines I need to get commented. I could be easily looking at either an 100 hour college course equivalent of study period, or a 4 month long learning curve.

The thing is, I'm not using ready-made boards like Raspberry Pi, I'm trying to build my own board with widely used components readily available in the market. My board would be similar to a lot of devboards out there but it's not gonna have a doppelganger with all the same properties/specs, so I pretty much have to build my own bootloader from uboot.

Ideas? Or did I get completely the wrong idea?

Anyway if this is going to be way too time-consuming I suppose I'll use RPi whatnot.

Answer (score 2):

You've got the wrong idea.  It's a combination of a Kconfig-style .config and editing the include/config/boardname.h header file that you create based on the reference platform that you start with for your board (even if not starting with a reference HW design and customizing you should pick a best-fit for the SoC that already exists and go from there).

Comment: Doesn't U-Boot switch to use device tree like blobs to configure boards (instead of board files)?

Comment: Device trees are used (and usage is growing) as a way to describe the hardware.  So information that may previously have been in a header file would now be read from the device tree that is passed in.  So yes, device trees play a part as well, and we strive to be compatible with the same one used by Linux, so effort would not be duplicated.  Board files do not however go away entirely.

Comment: My point that we have encourage people to use device tree, not the board files.